# How to treat AJAX response as a new page visit

Tags: ajax, fetch-api

I have an endpoint that can accept a various HTTP verbs, and will return XML with a processing instruction. I cannot send the PUT request with an ordinary HTML form, so I need to use the fetch() API or XMLHttpRequest. Is it possible to have the request accept the response and regardless of what the response is treat it as a regular page visit, so the browser will run the XSLT transform and show the resulting page, as if I had submitted a POST request? Ideally, it'd treat the resulting document exactly as if I had navigated to it, error screens on bad XSLT transforms and all.

I am hoping to avoid spoofing with a _method form input and such tricks if I can.